# Alternative to CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT in BigQuery, with a LAG() function?

Tags: google-bigquery, window-functions, vertica

Vertica has a very nice type of operations: **Event-Based Window** operations, which basically let you identify when an event occurs. For example the **CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT** will increment a counter each time the given boolean expression resolves to true.

Is there any way I can emulate this function using BigQuery? Please note that there is a **LAG() function** within the **CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT** one.

Example:

```
CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT(timestamp - LAG(timestamp) > '7 days')
OVER(PARTITION BY zuid, sub_type ORDER BY timestamp)
```

Thanks!

Comment: looks relatively simple - but can you please provide simple example of input data and expected result so there is no chance for misreading your question :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery

```
select zuid, sub_type, timestamp, 
  countif(flag) over(partition by zuid, sub_type order by timestamp) as conditional_true_event
from (
  select zuid, sub_type, timestamp,
    date(timestamp) - 7 > lag(date(timestamp)) over(partition by zuid, sub_type order by timestamp) flag
  from `project.dataset.table`
)
-- order by timestamp
```

Answer (score 1):

I had played with that question a few times.

It's actually about nesting two queries to get there:

First query (using Common Table Expressions) introduces a counter that is at 1 when the condition you're after is true, and at 0 otherwise.
Second query, querying the first query's output, creates a running sum of that counter.

It's considerably clumsier than the Vertica version that I show below the BigQuery version ...

Let me use the example I played with: sensor data with timestamps and with an oil pressure measure. We want to separate "trips" that we can only identify because there's an over 30-min gap between "trips".

The BigQuery version - and it works with all DBMS-s that support the LAG() OLAP function ...

```
WITH
-- input ...
oilpressure(vid,ts,psi) AS (
            SELECT 42,TIMESTAMP '2020-10-01 17:00:00', 25.356
  UNION ALL SELECT 42,TIMESTAMP '2020-10-01 17:00:10', 35.124
  UNION ALL SELECT 42,TIMESTAMP '2020-10-01 17:00:20', 47.056
  UNION ALL SELECT 42,TIMESTAMP '2020-10-01 17:00:30', 45.225
  UNION ALL SELECT 42,TIMESTAMP '2020-10-01 17:45:00', 25.356
  UNION ALL SELECT 42,TIMESTAMP '2020-10-01 17:45:10', 35.124
  UNION ALL SELECT 42,TIMESTAMP '2020-10-01 17:45:20', 47.056
  UNION ALL SELECT 42,TIMESTAMP '2020-10-01 17:45:30', 45.225
)
,
with_chg_counter AS (
  SELECT
    CASE WHEN ts - LAG(ts,1,'0000-01-01') OVER w > '30 MINUTES'
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END AS chg
  , *
  FROM oilpressure
  WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY vid ORDER BY ts)
)
SELECT
  vid
, SUM(chg) OVER w AS tripid
, ts
, psi
FROM with_chg_counter
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY vid ORDER BY ts)
;
-- out vid|tripid|ts                 |psi
-- out  42|     1|2020-10-01 17:00:00|25.356
-- out  42|     1|2020-10-01 17:00:10|35.124
-- out  42|     1|2020-10-01 17:00:20|47.056
-- out  42|     1|2020-10-01 17:00:30|45.225
-- out  42|     2|2020-10-01 17:45:00|25.356
-- out  42|     2|2020-10-01 17:45:10|35.124
-- out  42|     2|2020-10-01 17:45:20|47.056
-- out  42|     2|2020-10-01 17:45:30|45.225
```

And the Vertica version ...

```
WITH
oilpressure(vid,ts,psi) AS (
            SELECT 42,TIMESTAMP '2020-10-01 17:00:00', 25.356
  UNION ALL SELECT 42,TIMESTAMP '2020-10-01 17:00:10', 35.124
  UNION ALL SELECT 42,TIMESTAMP '2020-10-01 17:00:20', 47.056
  UNION ALL SELECT 42,TIMESTAMP '2020-10-01 17:00:30', 45.225
  UNION ALL SELECT 42,TIMESTAMP '2020-10-01 17:45:00', 25.356
  UNION ALL SELECT 42,TIMESTAMP '2020-10-01 17:45:10', 35.124
  UNION ALL SELECT 42,TIMESTAMP '2020-10-01 17:45:20', 47.056
  UNION ALL SELECT 42,TIMESTAMP '2020-10-01 17:45:30', 45.225
)
SELECT
  vid
, CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT(
    ts - LAG(ts,1,'0000-01-01') > '30 MINUTES'
  ) OVER w AS tripid
, ts
, psi
FROM oilpressure
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY vid ORDER BY ts)
;
-- out  vid | tripid |         ts          |  psi   
-- out -----+--------+---------------------+--------
-- out   42 |      1 | 2020-10-01 17:00:00 | 25.356
-- out   42 |      1 | 2020-10-01 17:00:10 | 35.124
-- out   42 |      1 | 2020-10-01 17:00:20 | 47.056
-- out   42 |      1 | 2020-10-01 17:00:30 | 45.225
-- out   42 |      2 | 2020-10-01 17:45:00 | 25.356
-- out   42 |      2 | 2020-10-01 17:45:10 | 35.124
-- out   42 |      2 | 2020-10-01 17:45:20 | 47.056
-- out   42 |      2 | 2020-10-01 17:45:30 | 45.225
```